# ActiveRecord models interdependencies and correlations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, database-design, model

I have a bunch of AR models that depend one to each other and I'm not able to figure out how to make everything work together...

First of all a Pet and a Dog model:

```
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :animal, polymorphic: true, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :facility
  has_many :pet_pictures, dependent: :destroy
  validates :name, :birth, :facility, :pet_pictures, presence: true
end

class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :pet, as: :animal
  has_many :mixtures, as: :blended, dependent: :destroy
  validates :mixtures, presence: true
end
```

Then both PetPictures and Mixtures:

```
class PetPicture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pet
  validates :photo_file, presence: true
end

class Mixture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blended, polymorphic: true
  validates :breed, presence: true
  validates :breed, uniqueness: { scope: [:blended_id, :blended_type] }
end
```

The problem is that this is too complex and I'm having huge problem coordinating all the dependencies, I also had to remove some validations (a pic MUST have a pet related to it, but it's so difficult that I ended up removing it). It appears to me that there's no correct order of creation to end up with a valid object.

For example, take this spec:

```
RSpec.describe PetPicture, type: :model do
  let(:dog) do
    FactoryGirl.build(:marley,
                       mixtures: [mixture_yorkshire, mixture_dachsund],
                       pet: FactoryGirl.build(
                         :dog,
                         pet_pictures: [FactoryGirl.build(:marleys_pic),
                                    FactoryGirl.build(:second_marleys_pic)],
                         facility: lida))
  end

  context 'when creating' do
    it 'should be valid' do
      # dog.save && dog.pet.save
      dog.pet.pictures.each do |picture|
        expect(picture).to be_valid
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This spec passes only after saving by hand (if I FactoryGirl.create nothing is created due to validation errors related to the order of creation) *BUT*, and I seriously see no reason for this behavior, picture.pet_id is NULL.

Can you help me debug this? Any suggestion or link on how to improve/refactor/cleanup this mess is very welcome - just keep in mind that I adopted this for a reason, so a Pet has many pictures and can be a Dog, a Cat or whatever, which have all a different set of attributes very specific to their class. Also, a Dog can be 50% dachsund and 50% yorkshire, to explain the mixtures relation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are trying to check for every validations, you should do it one at a time, don't try create a bunch of them. For example:

```
RSpec.describe PetPicture, type: :model do
  let(:pet) { FactoryGirl.create(:pet) }
  let(:picture) do
    FactoryGirl.build(:marleys_pic, pet: pet)
  end

  context 'when creating' do
    it 'should be valid' do
      expect(picture).to be_valid
    end
  end
end
```

And if you want something really clean and clear, try [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers). Every associations and validations could be tested by only 1 line of code.